# Derby doesn't work when using PHP-Java-Bridge, Why?

Tags: java, hibernate, derby, php-java-bridge

When I access derby through netbeans and log the results everything I get good data,
but when I do the exact same thing through PHP-Java Bridge I get no data.
In package:

com.m1sk.HelloBridge

```
 public static String backTest() throws Exception
    {
         BackendLink back = new BackendLink();
        return back.GetTourists();
    }
```

When called though the main I get something like this:

```
[{<Json Representation of the only object in the database>}]
```

This is good,
 but When I call this function with PHP-Java Bridge

```
<?
$test = new Java("com.m1sk.HelloBridge");
echo "!!<br>";
echo $test->backTest();
?>
```

I get

```
!!
[]
```

Basically it calls the function but for some reason when it accesses the actual database it doesnt get the same thing!

**Edit**

*Backend_DAO_DB_impl:*

```
EntityManager em;
public Backend_DAO_DB_impl()
{
    String PersistenceName = "XYZ;
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceName);
    em =emf.createEntityManager();
}

public ArrayList<Tourist> GetTourists()
{
    Query q = em.createQuery("from Tourist");
    return (ArrayList<Tourist>) q.getResultList();
}
```

*BackendLink*

```
public String GetTourists() throws Exception
{
     ArrayList<Tourist> tourists = back.GetTourists();
    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
    for(Tourist t : tourists)
    {
       arr.add(JSONConverter.touristToJSON(t));
    }
    return arr.toJSONString();
}
```

back is an object of Backend_DAO_DB_impl
The BackendLink works at least when running in eclipse. 
The problem isnt with the JSONConverter, I checked.
So It must be something deeper in the code, meaning its probably 
something in derby or hibernate.

My current guess is that netbeans does something automatically that i'm not doing with the java bridge.
**Edit**
As requested here are the logs:
Catalina

```
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: java5772_5140_9448_modelDB.TouristSite
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder bindTable
INFO: Bind entity java5772_5140_9448_modelDB.TouristSite on table TouristSite
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: java5772_5140_9448_modelDB.InsideSites
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: java5772_5140_9448_modelDB.OutsideSites
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: java5772_5140_9448_modelDB.TourReservation
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder bindTable
INFO: Bind entity java5772_5140_9448_modelDB.TourReservation on table TourReservation
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: java5772_5140_9448_modelDB.Tourist
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder bindTable
INFO: Bind entity java5772_5140_9448_modelDB.Tourist on table Tourist
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration secondPassCompile
**INFO: Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring**
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: autocommit mode: true
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: using driver: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver at URL: jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
INFO: connection properties: {user=app, password=****, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: RDBMS: Apache Derby, version: 10.8.1.2 - (1095077)
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC driver: Apache Derby Network Client JDBC Driver, version: 10.2.2.1 - (538595)
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory buildTransactionFactory
INFO: Transaction strategy: org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory getTransactionManagerLookup
INFO: No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Scrollable result sets: enabled
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): disabled
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Connection release mode: auto
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Default batch fetch size: 1
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Generate SQL with comments: disabled
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory createQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO: Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Query language substitutions: {}
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: JPA-QL strict compliance: enabled
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Second-level cache: enabled
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Query cache: disabled
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory createCacheProvider
INFO: Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Statistics: disabled
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Default entity-mode: pojo
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
INFO: Named query checking : enabled
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl <init>
INFO: building session factory
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory addInstance
INFO: Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:06 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: exporting generated schema to database
Jul 25, 2012 9:16:08 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport execute
INFO: schema export complete
```

The other ones seem OK. Im not really sure about that line.

Comment: Try not using "static" modifier.

Comment: doesnt change anything, it seems to be something to do with the database access.

Comment: any exceptions that are being thrown? I would suspect some kind of lack of initialization for the php bridge.

Comment: I thought so to, but if there was any exception then then I wouldnt get a result like this "[]" but rather some sort of blue apache exception page!

Comment: @m1sk no, you would not receive any "blue apache exception page". You need to check your server logs.

Comment: @Jaec I add the logs! but I dont really understand them so I cant figure out the problem.